# Agrupar 2 count() en una consulta en PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estas son las tablas de mi base de datos:

**animal**

```
 _________________
|id_animal | zona |
|__________|______|
| T1       | 01   |
|__________|______|
| B1       | 01   |
|__________|______|
| C1       | 01   |
|__________|______|
| C2       | 01   |
|__________|______|
| B1       | 02   |
|__________|______|
```

**donacion**

```
 _______________________________
|id_animal | c_especie | status |
|__________|___________|________|
| T1       | 1         | 0      |
|__________|___________|________|
| B1       | 2         | 1      |
|__________|___________|________|
| C1       | 3         | 1      |
|__________|___________|________|
| C2       | 3         | 0      | 
|__________|___________|________|
| B1       | 2         | 1      |
|__________|___________|________|
```

**especie**

```
 ___________________________
|c_especie | nombre_especie |
|__________|________________|
|  1       | felinos        |
|__________|________________|
|  2       | anfibios       |
|__________|________________|
|  3       | reptiles       |
|__________|________________|
```

Necesito una consulta que muestre los resultados del total de donaciones y el total de animales que no han recibido una donación agrupado nombre de especie DE LA ZONA 01, en la tabla donaciones la columna status refiere a 1 (donación) y 0 (sin donación), es decir el resultado deseado es el siguiente

```
 ________________________________________________
| nombre_especie | Total_donaciones | Sin_apoyo  |
|________________|__________________|____________|
| felinos        | 0                |  1         |
|________________|__________________|____________|
| anfibios       | 1                |  0         |
|________________|__________________|____________|
| reptiles       | 1                |  1         |
|________________|__________________|____________|
```

Este es el código que obtiene la primeras 2 columnas (nombre_especie | Total_donaciones), pero no se como anidar la tercera columna (Sin_apoyo)

```
select e.nombre_especie, count (d.id_animal) AS Total_donaciones 
from especie e, donacion d, animal a 
where e.c_especie = d.c_especie
      and d.id_animal = a.id_animal
      and d.status = 1 
      and a.zona = 01
group by e.nombre_especie
order by e.nombre_especie ASC;
```

Estoy trabajando en postgres, de antemano les agradezco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya tengo la consulta que necesitas, espero te sea de ayuda y que ayuden a muchos animales, saludos.

```
select e.c_especie, e.nombre_especie, count(d.`status`) as sum,
(
    select count(*) 
    from donacion d2, animal a2
    where d2.`status`=0 and d2.c_especie=e.c_especie and a2.zona=01 and a2.id_animal=d2.id_animal
) AS sin_apoyo

from (animal a inner join donacion d
on a.id_animal=d.id_animal and a.zona=01 and d.`status`=1) 
right join especie e on e.c_especie=d.c_especie
group by d.c_especie
ORDER BY e.nombre_especie
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. Me arroja este error @the-breaker ERROR:  la subconsulta usa la columna «e.c_especie» no agrupada de una consulta exterior
LINE 5:     where d2.status= 0 and d2.c_especie=e.c_especie

Comment: ya esta, puedes probarlo @Indiradev26

Comment: en sin_apoyo me esta arrojando valores incorrectos, creo que esta sumando todas las especies de todas las zonas, ya que aunque cambie la zona en el where me arroja los mismos resultados, no entiendo muy bien sum(d.status) ya que aqui deberìa ser el total de status = 1 y no la suma de todos los status

Comment: @Indiradev26, ya modifique la consulta, solo había probado con los datos que dejaste de ejemplo, ya probé con mas datos, espero que esta ya sea la correcta.

Comment: muchas gracias @the-breaker, funciona muy bien